# Error in Customized Procedure "Must declare the scalar variable @startdate"

Tags: sql-server, database, date

I have a procedure to fetch data as per the criteria passed. I works fine with @month, @year, @quater.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SPReportTimeSpan
    (
    @Week int = null,
    @Month int = null,
    @Year int = null,
    @Quater int = null
    )
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)

    If (@Week) IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @startdate Date, @enddate Date
        EXEC dbo.SPReturnStartEndDateOfSpecifiedWeek  @Week, @startdate OUTPUT, @enddate OUTPUT 
        SELECT @startdate, @enddate
    END

    SELECT @sql='SELECT
    CRMDR.Id as Id,.  
    CRMDR.Request_For_Id as Request_For_Id

    From [CRM].[dbo].[CRM_Doctor_Request] AS CRMDR

    WHERE CRMDR.Is_Deleted=0 '
    If (@Month) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND MONTH(CRMDR.Date_Created) like (@Month)  '
    If (@Year) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND YEAR(CRMDR.Date_Created) like (@Year) '
    If (@Week) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND (CRMDR.Date_Created) BETWEEN (@startdate) AND (@enddate) '
    If (@Quater) IS NOT NULL
        IF (@Quater = 1)
            SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND MONTH(CRMDR.Date_Created) in (4,5,6) '
        IF (@Quater = 2)
            SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND MONTH(CRMDR.Date_Created) in (7,8,9) '
        IF (@Quater = 3)
            SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND MONTH(CRMDR.Date_Created) in (10,11,12) '
        IF (@Quater = 4)
            SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND MONTH(CRMDR.Date_Created) in (1,2,3) '


    SELECT @sql=@sql + ' ORDER BY CRMDR.Id DESC '

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Month int, @Year int, @Quater int', 
                   @Month, @Year, @Quater

    RETURN
```

But for @week it gives error.

```
Running [dbo].[SPReportTimeSpan] ( @Week = 3, @Month = <NULL>, @Year = <NULL>, @Quater = <NULL> ).

Must declare the scalar variable "@startdate".
Column1                        Column2                        
------------------------------ ------------------------------ 
2013-02-10 00:00:00.0000000    2013-02-17 00:00:00.0000000    
No rows affected.
(1 row(s) returned)
@RETURN_VALUE = 0
Finished running [dbo].[SPReportTimeSpan].
```

I am not getting why its not working with week criteria. Please help if anyone have idea.

Answer (score 3):

`@startdate` and `@enddate` are only accessible within the scope of your `IF` statement:

```
If (@Week) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DECLARE @startdate Date, @enddate Date
    EXEC dbo.SPReturnStartEndDateOfSpecifiedWeek  @Week, @startdate OUTPUT, @enddate OUTPUT 
    SELECT @startdate, @enddate
END
```

Move the declaration outside of the `IF` statement if you wish to reference these variables elsewhere:

```
DECLARE @startdate Date, @enddate Date
If (@Week) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN        
    EXEC dbo.SPReturnStartEndDateOfSpecifiedWeek  @Week, @startdate OUTPUT, @enddate OUTPUT 
    SELECT @startdate, @enddate
END
```

---

FYI: The area where you make reference to these variables outside of the `IF` statement is here:

```
If (@Week) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND (CRMDR.Date_Created) BETWEEN (@startdate) AND (@enddate) '
```

Answer (score 1):

I got solution of my problem. To solve the problem, I need to explicitly cast  datetime values to a character type so the query string can be concatenated as expected.

```
If (@Week) IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND (CRMDR.Date_Created) BETWEEN ''' + convert(VARCHAR,@startdate) + ''' AND ''' +convert(VARCHAR,@enddate) + ''''
```

or this (More Optimized)

```
SELECT @sql=@sql + ' AND (CRMDR.Date_Created BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)'
```

which needs to add something to `sp_executesql`

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Month int, @Year int, @Quater int, @Week int, @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime ', 
     @Month, @Year, @Quater, @Week, @startdate, @enddate
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are [out of scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29).